# How do I efficiently and briefly add columns of a partial table?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to use native python and write a terse code as much as possible to achieve this.
So with table A as below:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

| 4 | 5 | 6 |

Then the list A is given as following

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

And suppose the task is to sum first two columns of A into a list B.

I tried naive approach of using a nested for loop. (which works)

```
n = 2
B = [0] * n
for row in range(len(A)):
    for col in range(n):
        B[col] += A[row][col]
```

I tried list comprehension

```
B = [sum(x) for x in zip(*A)][:n]
```

But the problem is that I don't want to go through all the columns and then later split list B. I'd like to avoid computing elements that's going to be later thrown away.

What would be the most efficient and concise way to solve this task?

Comment: This is a List of Lists, not a table and there are no rows nor columns,  Numpy is the obvious approach but you seem to want only basic Python which will inevitably be more complicated when you impose column-like thinking.

Comment: @user19077881 table and its rows and columns mentioned in the post refer to general idea of tables and their rows and columns and are not specific to programming languages

Comment: I know that. But thinking of rows and columns for Python Lists can lead to tangles in more complex data. A List is a sequence of values which can be accessed using the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid computing unnecessary values in the list comprehension, you would want to slice `zip(*A)`, not the final list.

Since `zip` returns an iterator, not a list, you can't use `[:n]`.

But you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

B = [sum(x) for x in islice(zip(*A), n)]
```

Comment: `A` is not defined in your code

Comment: @XMehdi01 I'm assuming the definition from the code in the question is used.

Answer (score 0):

My code , `zip(*A)` transposes the original matrix, and then the list comprehension sums the first n elements in each transposed row.

```py
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
n = 2
B = [sum(row[:n]) for row in zip(*A)][:-1]
print(B)
#[5, 7]
```